# How to use $unwind and $match with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a document of the following format:

```
{
  "P": {
        "Workspaces": [
           {
              "Key": "Value1",
              "Size": 2.27,
              "Status": 'something'
           },
            {
              "Key": "Value2",
              "Size": 3.27,
              "Status": 'somethingelse'
           }
         ]
     }
}
```

The following query returns the average correctly.

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
          { $unwind: "$P.Workspaces" }, 
          { $group: { _id: "$P.Workspaces.Key", average: { $avg: "$P.Workspaces.Size" } } } 
      ])
```

I am trying to add a match to filter the status as shown below. However I am not getting no result even though there are documents with matching status. I am trying to filter the results before taking the average. Am I missing something here?

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
  { $unwind: "$P.Workspaces" }, 
  { $match: { "P.Workspaces.Status":'something'}},
  { $group: { _id: "$P.Workspaces.Key", average: { $avg: "$P.Workspaces.Size" } } } 
  ])
```

Comment: I copied and pasted this exactly as you have it and it's working for me.

Comment: It should work. I cannot see any issue in the above query

Comment: Thanks, there was a typo in my bigger query, which was not there when I minimized it for posting here!

Comment: Something else to keep in mind: it's good practice to duplicate the $match stage before $unwind when doing $unwind -> $match. The first $match will return only documents that contain at least one `P.Workspaces` entry where `Status` is 'something'. This will reduce the number of documents entering the aggregation pipeline, while also allowing the operation to use an index on that field. (The aggregation as-is will do a collection scan). The 2nd match will then filter out all the other entries in the 'Workspaces' array where 'Status' is not 'something'.

Comment: thanks for  the tip!

Answer (score 0):

```
db.articles.aggregate(
[ { $match : { author : "dave" } } ]
);
```

The examples use a collection named articles with the following documents:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("512bc95fe835e68f199c8686"), "author" : "dave", "score" : 80, "views" : 100 } { "_id" : ObjectId("512bc962e835e68f199c8687"), "author" : "dave", "score" : 85, "views" : 521 } { "_id" : ObjectId("55f5a192d4bede9ac365b257"), "author" : "ahn", "score" : 60, "views" : 1000 } { "_id" : ObjectId("55f5a192d4bede9ac365b258"), "author" : "li", "score" : 55, "views" : 5000 } { "_id" : ObjectId("55f5a1d3d4bede9ac365b259"), "author" : "annT", "score" : 60, "views" : 50 }
```

Comment: The examples use a collection named articles with the following documents:
{ "_id" : ObjectId("512bc95fe835e68f199c8686"), "author" : "dave", "score" : 80, "views" : 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("512bc962e835e68f199c8687"), "author" : "dave", "score" : 85, "views" : 521 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f5a192d4bede9ac365b257"), "author" : "ahn", "score" : 60, "views" : 1000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f5a192d4bede9ac365b258"), "author" : "li", "score" : 55, "views" : 5000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f5a1d3d4bede9ac365b259"), "author" : "annT", "score" : 60, "views" : 50 }